# Auto increment one column of a 3-column composite primary key in postgresql table

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I have three columns as a composite primary key in a table of PostgreSql database. Data for two columns will be provided in insert query. But another column has to be incremented every time insertion happens. Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE "food_index_directory" (
  "primary_key_one"          VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  "primary_key_two"          NUMERIC(4) NOT NULL,
  "primary_key_three"        NUMERIC(5) NOT NULL,
  "varchar_column_one"       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  "numeric_column_one"       INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "numeric_column_two"       NUMERIC(12,9) DEFAULT .001 NOT NULL,
  "numeric_column_three"     NUMERIC(5,2),
  "last_upd_date"            DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "PK_dummy_table" PRIMARY KEY ("primary_key_one","primary_key_two","primary_key_three")
);
```

As I said above, data for two primary key columns and another(`primary_key_three`) has to be incremented based on number of occurrences of first and second key columns. Second key column can only take values from 1 to 12, this third column is a count column for second column.
ex:

```
primary_key_one primary_key_two primary_key_three     ......
91                    1            1                 ......
91                    1            2                 ......
 91                    2            1                 ......
 91                    2            2                 ......
91                    1            3                 ......
 91                    2            3                 ......
  91                    3            1                 ......
 91                    2            4                 ......
  34                    3            1                 ......
91                    1            4                 ......
    91                   4            1                 ......
     91                   5            1                 ......
    34                   4            1                 ......
```

In the above example, (I have made spaces for better understanding, when data in first two columns are repeated), third column counts number of times first two columns have repeated in this table.

During Insert, I will be providing data for first two columns and the third column has to increment automatically as shown and explained above? How do I do this?

Comment: you can use trigger for your requirement.

Comment: I don't know how to write a trigger. Will you please be able to write it and answer my question @AkhileshMishra?

Comment: posted the trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "fn_trig_pk"()
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."trigger" AS $BODY$ 
begin
new.primary_key_three = (select count(*)+1 from food_index_directory where primary_key_one=new.primary_key_one and primary_key_two=new.primary_key_two );
return NEW;
end;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

and Trigger for your Table

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_pk
  BEFORE insert 
  ON food_index_directory
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_trig_pk();
```

Comment: I now have one doubt. After this trigger, can i not specify value for `primary_key_three` in `INSERT` statement and will it be executed without issues?

Comment: if you specify the value for the column `primary_key_three`, trigger will overwrite it as per its logic. if you will not provide the value for column it will add the value for `primary_key_three `

Comment: I mean to ask, after this not specify the `primary_key_three` column name and also not prove any value for it, like fire example:  `INSERT INTO food_index_directory (primary_key_one, primary_key_two, varchar_column_one, numeric_column_one, numeric_column_two, numeric_column_three
VALUES (value1, value2,,,,,,,);`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: No, `"fn_trig_pk"()` can be replaced with `"schema_name"."trigger_name"`. `RETURNS "pg_catalog"."trigger"` you have to keep as it is.